# CSS overflow auto doesn't work when container has min and max height

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with min and max height.

Inside there are 2 column style divs one with width 80% and other 20%

The one with 80% will have an `<img />` taking full height and width of its container.

The 20% one will have thumbnails. I set overflow auto on this one so that user can scroll through thumbnails and select one, but overflow auto is not having any effect. I cannot set exact height of container as it must be variable.

How can I get a overflow with scroll bar working in the div with thumbnails ?

Please refer to this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/el2KNvEJdpUfA6v24uTV?p=preview

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-main">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-list">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=1" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=2" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=3" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<style>
 .container{
    min-width: 420px;
    min-height: 316px;
    max-height: 337px;
    max-width: 540px;
}
.gallery-main{
    width: 79%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-height: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: inherit;
    max-height:100%;
}

.gallery-list img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.img-container {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: inherit;
}
.img-container img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Solution was to have position of relative on container and absolute on the misbehaving divs. (It appears, CSS is not exact science). Updated Plunker with solution so others can find it: https://plnkr.co/edit/el2KNvEJdpUfA6v24uTV?p=preview

Comment: check my answer please - I think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Here's a snippet for mine.  I think this does what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
.container{
      min-width: 420px;
    min-height: 316px;
    max-height: 337px;
    max-width: 540px;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery-main{
    width: 79%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-height: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: inherit;
  max-height:100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.gallery-list img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.img-container {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img-container img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-main">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-list">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=1" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=2" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=3" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=4" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=5" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=6" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=7" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=8" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=9" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=10" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=11" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your solution worked adpro. Adding position relative and absolute to container and .gallery-list did the trick. I am not sure why it worked though. If you can explain why, it would be great.

Comment: I believe it is due to a lack of height being applied to container.  It has max-height and min-height, but it doesn't respect those as much as an explicit height. Or, that's what I gather from years of CSS experience. Playing around with position seems to be a solution to odd things like this that go against what common sense would have you believe to work. The .container will take on the full height without height being specified for it. I'm sure there's a good reason for it. I'll see what I can dig up, as I'm interested now.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with the .gallery-main class as well. Image with long vertical height is overflowing outside the container (.img-container) instead of scaling to fit the container. I set img to have max-height and max-width to 100%; but they aren't respected. Please take a look at .img-container and ".img-container img"

Comment: Try that - I just removed the max-height and max-width - I don't see what you're talking about, though.  You might need to play with position on those elements.

Comment: max-width and max-height are important. without them images would stretch out, breaking aspect ratio. I just used the same position trick and got what i wanted. updated the plunker here : https://plnkr.co/edit/el2KNvEJdpUfA6v24uTV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  .gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: inherit;
    max-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
  }
```

Use `position:fixed;` on `div` `gallery-list`.

Comment: That did not do help. If anything, it kinda made things worse.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

if you use `overflow: scroll` use below code

```
.gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 300px;
  }
```

or if you use `overflow: auto;` use this

```
 .gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: inherit;
    max-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
  }
```

```css
   .container{
      min-width: 420px;
    min-height: 316px;
    max-height: 337px;
    max-width: 540px;
}
.gallery-main{
  width: 79%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-height: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
 .gallery-list {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: inherit;
    max-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
  }

.gallery-list img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.img-container {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: inherit;
}
.img-container img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-main">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-list">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=1" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=2" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=3" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=4" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=5" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=6" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=7" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=8" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=9" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=10" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600?test=11" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't have fixed height of 300px hardcoded. position fixed didn't fix it